# mySql real escape string returning blank

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

I have a php program that uses cookies to store data across pages and redirects. I want to use mysql_real_escape_string() before sending them to my server, so far my code looks like this

```
$master_string = $_COOKIE["master_string"];
$order_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_COOKIE["name"]);
$order_mail = $_COOKIE["mail"];

echo $order_name;
```

I have already checked that my sqli connection has been made, the resulting data inserted to my table is blank and so is the echo.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the connection parameter in mysqli_real_escape_string($_COOKIE["name"]);

Correct syntax: `mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_COOKIE["name"]);`

Comment: I've tried that, yet it is only returning a string without escaping any slashes or \n from it

Comment: Please, store this returned data to database table and you will see the changes. mysqli_real_escape_string does not remove the special characters instead converts to htmlentities. When you echo htmlentities, it will display the character.

Comment: I did use the correct syntax and inserted the variable into my database and was still coming up with //'s

Comment: `$master_string = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_COOKIE["master_string"]);` I feel as though it may be the fact that I am using cookies

Answer (score 0):

First Check cookies working or not than

You need enable Mysqli_connect

```
$connection = mysqli_connect;
$order_name  = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection , trim($_COOKIE['name']));
```